# How to delete an application in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am trying to delete an application.
I have created a new application using `ng new`.
Now I want to delete that application.
Can I do it using CLI? Or can I delete the folder directly?

Comment: rm -r YOUR APP NAME

Answer (score 12):

Probably you mean deleting a project in Angular multi-project workspace.
To do it:

1. Remove block for project in angular.json
2. Delete project folder in workspace
3. Delete project folder in dist folder
4. Be sure that all Node.js processes are closed (e.g. in Task Manager, if you use Windows)

Answer (score 3):

There is no CLI option for delete. You can manually delete the folder.

Comment: You also need to remove it from angular.json

Answer (score 3):

1. if you have started npm start or ng serve, Stop them first.
2. Delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the Server :
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

and manually delete the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for deletion with command line:

You must delete it manually, you can directly delete or use the rmdir command or del command in cmd prompt. But you also need to use /s option to recursively on rmdir do that with the project folder else it won't go ahead.